# What causes a type error in Next.js when run the build command and how can it be resolved?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

## Type error when I run `npm run build` in Next.js

```
- info Linting and checking validity of types .Failed to compile.

.next/types/app/success/page.ts:25:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<SuccessProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'id' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I have the following component

```js
export default function Success({ id, name }: SuccessProps) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <strong>{name}</strong> inscricao feita com sucesso
      <br />
      <p>Referencia da inscricao: {id}</p>

      <button className="btn btn-blue bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
        Sair
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export type SuccessProps = {
  id: any
  name: string
};
```

the parent component. In localhost everything runs fine. The problem only occurs when I run the build.
The Id is a string property return from the backend.

```js
export default function Home() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<UserModel>();
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<SuccessProps>();

  const onSubmit = async (formData: UserModel) => {
    const response = await fetch('/api', {
      ...
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    const responseData = await response.json();

    setIsSubmitted(true);
    setData({ id: responseData.id, name: formData.name });
  };

  if (isSubmitted && data) {
    return <Success id={data.id} name={data.name} />;
  }

  return ...
}
```

Solve the type error and understand why that happens.